# Is it possible to get an XInput device's name, product ID, vendor ID or some other kind of unique identifier for it?

Tags: windows, xinput

Ordinarily XInput controllers are identified simply using an index corresponding to the player number of the controller. Is there a way to obtain more information about a controller with a specific index, such as its vendor ID, product ID, or device name?

Even better would be a identifier that corresponds uniquely and consistently to just that controller so that it can be distinguished from all other XInput devices regardless of its index, including another controller that's an identical model (i.e. same product and vendor ID), similar to the instance GUID available using DirectInput.

Can this be accomplished using XInput or another Microsoft API? I'm also open to using undocumented functions if need be.

Comment: What happened to the identical question you asked just days ago?

Comment: @IInspectable It was voted to be closed as looking for a suggestion for software or a library, which as near as I can tell was done by people who didn't understand the question. I'm trying again and trying to make it very explicit I'm looking for a solution to a specific problem.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few undocumented functions inside the XInput1_4.dll. You can get the Vendor ID and Product ID like this:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Xinput.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct XINPUT_CAPABILITIES_EX
{
    XINPUT_CAPABILITIES Capabilities;
    WORD vendorId;
    WORD productId;
    WORD revisionId;
    DWORD a4; //unknown
};

typedef DWORD(_stdcall* _XInputGetCapabilitiesEx)(DWORD a1, DWORD dwUserIndex, DWORD dwFlags, XINPUT_CAPABILITIES_EX* pCapabilities);
_XInputGetCapabilitiesEx XInputGetCapabilitiesEx;

void main()
{
    HMODULE moduleHandle = LoadLibrary(TEXT("XInput1_4.dll"));
    XInputGetCapabilitiesEx = (_XInputGetCapabilitiesEx)GetProcAddress(moduleHandle, (char*)108);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        printf("Gamepad %d ", i);

        XINPUT_CAPABILITIES_EX capsEx;
        if (XInputGetCapabilitiesEx(1, i, 0, &capsEx) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("connected, vid = 0x%04X pid = 0x%04X\n", (int)capsEx.vendorId, (int)capsEx.productId);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("not connected\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer really helped me a lot, thanks!!!

Comment: This seems to be the answer I'm looking for but I get build errors when using this code. fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found.  My fix was to make the varaible static: static _XInputGetCapabilitiesEx XInputGetCapabilitiesEx;

Answer (score 1):

What XInput internally does is open a device, then call `DeviceIoControl` on it every time it reads the joypad.  (control code 0x8000e00c)

You need to hook these functions imported by "XInput1_4.dll":

- `CreateFileW` from "api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll"
- `DuplicateHandle` from "api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll"
- `CloseHandle` from "api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll"
- `DeviceIoControl` from "api-ms-win-core-io-l1-1-0.dll"

Using the hooks for `CreateFileW`, `DuplicateHandle` and `CloseHandle`, you can keep track of what filename is associated with a handle.

Then when you see a call to `DeviceIoControl` with control code 0x8000e00c, you will know what filename is being read.

---

The first time you call `XInputGetState`, it will open multiple devices, and call `DeviceIoControl` multiple times, regardless of what player number you have asked for.  You are only interested in the last filename seen by `DeviceIoControl` before `XInputGetState` returns.  And if `XInputGetState` indicates the controller is not plugged in, disregard the filename you have collected for that controller number.

---

Examples of filenames I have seen on my own computer:

- `\\?\hid#{00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}&vid_045e&pid_02e0&ig_00#8&7074921&2&0000#{ec87f1e3-c13b-4100-b5f7-8b84d54260cb}`
- `\\?\usb#vid_045e&pid_028e#1&1a590e2c&1&01#{ec87f1e3-c13b-4100-b5f7-8b84d54260cb}`

---

edit:

One more hook is required as well.

- `CoCreateInstance` from "api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll", to hook creating the undocumented `IDeviceBroker` COM object.  If it can successfully create an `IDeviceBroker` COM object, it will use that instead of the call to `CreateFileW`.  Parameters will be: `CLSID_DeviceBroker = {acc56a05-e277-4b1e-a43e-7a73e3cd6e6c}`, `IID_IDeviceBroker = {8604b268-34a6-4b1a-a59f-cdbd8379fd98}`.  The method `OpenDeviceFromInterfacePath` will be called instead of `CreateFileW`.  Alternatively, you can make creating the `IDeviceBroker` object simply fail, and it will proceed to use `CreateFileW` as usual.